# Append tag at the place of an Event

Tags: jquery

I have a Ul like this

```
<ul class="fine">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

On clicking Li i want to add an `<textarea>` under that corresponding li
like this

```
<li>One</li>
<li><textarea></textarea></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/), like this:

```
$(".fine").delegate("li", "click", function() {
  $(this).after("<li><textarea></textarea></li>");
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/EZm6g/), for older versions of jQuery (jQuery < 1.4.1) use a `click` event directly:

```
$(".fine li").click(function() {
  $(this).after("<li><textarea></textarea></li>");
});
```

For the delegate version, you may want to prevent adding when clicking the `<textarea>` elements themselves...that's easy enough, just give them a class and exclude it from the selector, like this:

```
$(".fine").delegate("li:not(.ta)", "click", function() {
  $(this).after("<li class='ta'><textarea></textarea></li>");
});
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/EZm6g/1/).

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
$('.fine li').live('click', function() { 
   $('<li><textarea></textarea></li>').prependTo($(this)); 
});
```

not tested

Comment: This would append to `<li>` to the current `<li>`, resulting in invalid HTML :)